# What this phrase "そういうつもりで" mean?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I found this phrase from a short manga strip.

> Man: ミチ子さん その金はもしかして...
>   Woman: 元々はあなたの金です。どうぞお取りください。
>   Man: え？
>
> Man: そういうつもりであげた金ではありません！それにこれを取ったらもうおわりってことですよね。
>   Woman: そうおっしゃらずに。
>   Man: でもボクまけちゃうんですよ。
>   Woman: これで終わりにしましょ。

It turns out they are playing Japanese chess.

My question is what does "そういうつもりであげた金ではありません" mean and how to use this phrase.

Thank you so so much.

Comment: [金]{かね} じゃなくて [金]{きん} だったのねww

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> そういうつもりであげた[金]{かね}ではありません！

You'd read the 金 as かね, "money", before you know they're playing 将棋. So you'd read this line as "I didn't mean that / It was not my intention when I gave you the money"... probably like 「別れるときに返してもらうつもりであげたお金ではありません。」 or even "I didn't give you the money for dating me", perhaps..

And you'd interpret:

> それにこれを取ったらもう終わりってことですよね。

implies their relationship will end if he gets the money back.

Aand... it turns out they're playing 将棋. Then you realise that the 金 was きん, 金将 (gold general), and these lines actually meant:

> そういうつもりであげた[金]{きん}ではありません！
>   それにこれを取ったらもう終わりってことですよね。

"I didn't mean/intend that when I gave you the 金将.
Also, if I get the 金将 back, the game will be over." (← The man loses the game)

Comment: Thank you so much Chocolate san. That's a very clear explanation.

Comment: 別れるときに返してもらうつもりであげたお金ではありません。」this means i didn't intend to give you the money to get it returned when we break up?

Comment: @user348715  そうですね。。 yes, I think so. (Sorry I wasn't sure how to say it in English..) I think it's literally like "I didn't give you the money with the intention of getting it returned when we break up"

Comment: Thanks again Chacolate san